# Get XPath from XML Document Present in Marklogic Database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am new to Marklogic and My Requirement is, I have XML document in Marklogic Database containing multiple elements.

```
 ** Example :**    

<tXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <Source>Source1</Source>
        <Action_Type>Action_Type1</Action_Type>
        <Sequence_Number>Sequence_Number1</Sequence_Number>
    </Header>
</tXML>
```

When i pass "**Sequence_Number**"it should return **/tXML/Header/Sequence_Number**
   and it is possible to have "**Sequence_Number**" element multiple times.

Please tell me whether it is possible using Marklogic XQuery/Java API or i need to uses any third party API to obtain this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably won't perform well on large documents, but you could use string matching on element names to find the elements, and then use [`xdmp:path`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:path) to get the corresponding XPath for that document. Something like:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $xml := document {
<tXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <Source>Source1</Source>
        <Action_Type>Action_Type1</Action_Type>
        <Sequence_Number>Sequence_Number1</Sequence_Number>
    </Header>
</tXML>
}
let $elem-name := "Sequence_Number"
let $elems := $xml//*[local-name() eq $elem-name]
return $elems ! xdmp:path(.)
```

HTH!

Comment: Even shorter (maybe a little more efficient) would be to avoid letting a variable with the matched elements, and simply return the sequence of XPaths:  `return $xml//*[local-name() eq $elem-name]/xdmp:path(.)`

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `String` "Sequence_Number" then how could it know which of the `Sequence_Number` siblings to get the XPath of? You could be talking about the first occurrence or maybe the second or third, it wont know. Given just a tagName, it can't know which occurrence to get the XPath for.

That said, the below method will give you the general XPath to where an element lives. You just need to get the `org.w3c.dom.Element` first, which can be gotten from the `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

```
public static String getXPathOfElement(org.w3c.dom.Element el) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(el);
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Node n = el; n != null; n = n.getParentNode()) {
        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            list.push(n.getNodeName());
        else
            list.push("");
    }
    return String.join("/", list);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    // Get an input stream of your Xml somehow
    String xml =
            "<tXML xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"
            + "<Header>"
            + "<Source>Source1</Source>"
            + "<Action_Type>Action_Type1</Action_Type>"
            + "<Sequence_Number>Sequence_Number1</Sequence_Number>"
            + "</Header>"
            + "</tXML>";

    java.io.InputStream xmlInputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

    // Get the Document from the xml InputStream
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFact =
            javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFact.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlInputStream);

    // Get the Element you want the general XPath of
    // In this case just find the first one with a certain tag in the Document
    org.w3c.dom.Element el =
            (org.w3c.dom.Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("Sequence_Number").item(0);

    System.out.println(getXPathOfElement(el));
}
```

Comment: Thanks xtratic for you reply but i can't go with this (org.w3c.dom.Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("Sequence_Number").item(0); and as i mentioned that Sequence_Number can repeat multiple times under  multiple parent nodes so i need xpath of all the occurrences of  Sequence_Number